# X-HTTP-Method-Override in Flask's Python Web server

Tags: python, http, flask, http-headers

I'm learning HTTP and I try to learn how different headers work. I want to implement a simple HTTP server using Flask and Python just to test the`X-HTTP-Method-Override` header.

My code:

```
class HTTPMethodOverrideMiddleware(object):
    allowed_methods = frozenset(
        ["GET", "HEAD", "POST", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"]
    )
    bodyless_methods = frozenset(["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "DELETE"])

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        method = environ.get("HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE", "").upper()
        if method in self.allowed_methods:
            environ["REQUEST_METHOD"] = method
        if method in self.bodyless_methods:
            environ["CONTENT_LENGTH"] = "0"
        return self.app(environ, start_response)


from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return request.method


app.wsgi_app = HTTPMethodOverrideMiddleware(app.wsgi_app)
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=9090)
```

When I'm sending this curl request:  `curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:9090"` server returns `GET`, which is OK, but with this: `curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:9090" --header "X-HTTP-Method-Override : POST"` it still shows `GET` instead of `POST`.

What is wrong? The code or curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in both code and curl command.

You need to allow the methods on the route, like this:

```py
@app.route("/", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def index():
  return request.method
```

This will allow `GET` and `POST` methods on the route, enabling you to execute the following commands:

```bash
curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:9090" --header "X-HTTP-Method-Override: POST"
```

```bash
curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:9090" --header "X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET"
```

You had spaces between `:` in the `--header` which caused it not parsing corrently.

Comment: Tested, works, thank you so much!